# How can I create an array of and Abstract class such that I can initialize it to a specific non-abstract class (java)

Tags: java, arrays, generics, multidimensional-array, abstract

I have an abstract class Agent and a bunch of classes that extend it, ModAgent, ClassAgent etc.

In another class Toroid I am holding a multidimensional array (well, nested array this being java) currently of type Agent[][].  What I would like is to be able to do is in the constructor for Toroid take a specific type of object that implements Agent, and declare/initialize the array to be of that specific type of Agent so that I can access specific methods in ClassAgent that are not declared in agent.  Can anyone instruct me on how to go about this?

Secondly, I have methods that return as a list smaller sections of that multidimensional array.  Like the array, the currently have a return type of Agent.  Is there a way to go about making that return type specific to the Agent type the Array is holding?

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like is to be able to do is in the constructor for Toroid take a specific type of object that implements Agent, and declare/initialize the array to be of that specific type of Agent

You can use something like

```
public class Toroid <A extends Agent> {
    private final A[][] agents;

    public Toroid(Class<A> aClass) {
        Class<A[]> aClassArray = (Class<A[]>) Array.newInstance(aClass, 0).getClass();
        agents = (A[][]) Array.newInstance(aClassArray, 100);
```

> so that I can access specific methods in ClassAgent that are not declared in agent.

That you can't do because A is only an Agent. If you want to use sepecific methods you will need to cast the objects.

> Is there a way to go about making that return type specific to the Agent type the Array is holding?

You can return `A[]`

Comment: there is no benefit to making a `A[][]` compared to just `Agent[][]`

Comment: @newacct I agree. Its extract complication but I suspect it won't do what the OP wants.